# Angularjs typescript wait end of function to run another function

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm developping a app in Angular CLI, and I would simply like to get a list after a insert. I've read and tried a lot of things (observer / promise / async / setTimeout / ...) after some researches, but couldn't find the right answer. I might not have been far.

Here is the code I have now. In insertStatut(), I'm doing the insertion (service.insertStatuts()) and right after the getStatuts() to update list.

Here is the code in my component :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatStatutService } from '../mat-statut.service';
import { MatStatut } from '../matStatut';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mat-statut',
  templateUrl: './mat-statut.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mat-statut.component.css']
})
export class MatStatutComponent implements OnInit {
  private statuts: MatStatut[];
  private inStatut = new MatStatut;

  constructor(private service:MatStatutService) {
  }

  // get statuts at launch
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getStatuts();
  }

  // get list of statuts
  public getStatuts(): void{
    this.service.getStatuts().subscribe(posts => this.statuts = posts);
    console.log(this.statuts);
  }

  // insert a new statut
  public insertStatut():void{
    this.inStatut.setLibelle('Test');
    // insert new statut
    this.service.insertStatut(this.inStatut);
    // refresh list of statuts
    this.getStatuts();
    // reset insertion Statut
    this.resetMatStatut(this.inStatut);
  }

  // reset statut
  public resetMatStatut(statut: MatStatut){
    statut.resetData();
  }
}
```

Here is the code in my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatStatut } from './matStatut';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MatStatutService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getStatuts(): Observable<MatStatut[]>{
    return this.http.get<MatStatut[]>('http://localhost/rest/fonctions/matStatut/getAll.php');
  }

  insertStatut(statut: MatStatut) {
    this.http.post('http://localhost/rest/fonctions/matStatut/create.php', {
      mat_statut_libelle: statut.getLibelle()})
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res);
        },
        err =>{
          console.log(err);
        });
  }
}
```

I hope my explainations are clear enought, and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: It's Angular, not AngularJS. `subscribe` is misused here. It's supposed to be used in place where results are consumed. You're really not using observable features that you could benefit from. For seamless chaining, stick to promises. They can be used as async..await.  The question doesn't show how exactly you tried to use them.

Comment: It's not terribly clear what results you get, or what results you expect. Maybe [edit] the question and tell us. What debugging have you tried? Tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is on inserStatus of MatStatutService, you can change for this:

```
insertStatut(statut: MatStatut) {
 return this.http.post('http://localhost/rest/fonctions/matStatut/create.php', {
  mat_statut_libelle: statut.getLibelle()});
}
```

In the component you should have:

```
public insertStatut():void{
 this.inStatut.setLibelle('Test');
 // insert new statut
 this.service.insertStatut(this.inStatut).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    // refresh list of statuts
    this.getStatuts();
    // reset insertion Statut
    this.resetMatStatut(this.inStatut);
 }
```

This ensures you that the insertion occurs first, and then you get the updated list.

P.s is Angular not Angularjs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution worked perfectly. It's really helping a lot, I was stucked for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Stephane, there are a lot of things that you make wrong

1.-A Service, generally must only return Observables. If you want to check all was ok you can use "pipe(tap)" if you're using Rxjx 6.0 or "do" if your'e using Rjxs 5.0

```
insertStatut(statut: MatStatut) {
    //just return httpPost
    return this.http.post('http://localhost/rest/fonctions/matStatut/create.php', {
      mat_statut_libelle: statut.getLibelle()}) //I use pipe.tap to show the result
      .pipe(tap(res=>{console.log(res)}))
  }
```

2.-Is your component, when call to insertStatus, when you subscribe to the Observable. And is INSIDE the "subscribe" where you put your code. outside subscribe, you have no value.

```
public insertStatut():void{
    this.inStatut.setLibelle('Test');
    // insert new statut
    this.service.insertStatut(this.inStatut).subscribe(res=>
      { //You can do something with the response
        //Or simply, call to Refresh de data
        //But INSIDE subscribe
       this.getStatuts();
       this.resetMatStatut(this.inStatut);
      };
    // the lines below have no sense, they are OUTSIDE
    //this.getStatuts();
    //this.resetMatStatut(this.inStatut);
  }
```

Of course your function getStatus() must be

```
  public getStatuts(): void{
    this.service.getStatuts().subscribe(posts => 
     { //Again console.log INSIDE
       this.statuts = posts;
       console.log(this.statuts);
     })
  }
```

NOTE: I just take acount I say the same that Luax :(

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. As LuaXD answered first, I tried his solution first, but you have exactly the same. Thanks for your time.